# How to build PHP 5.5 with FastCGI?

Tags: php5, apache-2.4

I need to build my own PHP binary under Unix (because I need some SGBD option, that's an other problem).

Currently my Apache server is linked to PHP throught CGI, but I read that it's not the recommended way (performance and security issues...), so I would like to built my PHP with FastCGI support.

[The PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/configure.about.php) tells me that `--enable-fastcgi` option doesn't exist anymore, and I should look at `--enable-cgi` option, but this option doesn't appear in the doc.

Does it mean that FastCgi is automatically enabled? If so how can I check that FastCGI is well installed?

I tried a `php -i | grep cgi` but it gives me nothing... And I find no  `mod_fastcgi.so` file built on my system, as far as I understand it should be produced by php build, shouldn't it?

#### Edit

`apachectl -M | grep cgi` gives:

```
proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
proxy_scgi_module (shared)
cgi_module (shared)
```

Comment: You might want to run apachectl -M (if your system supports it) to see the loaded modules.

Comment: @CobraKaiDojo Is `mod_proxy_fcgi` the same as `mod_fastcgi.so`? The [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html) about it let's think that it's harder to configurate than the no-proxy one's...